# Is it possible to add a rank to a continuous data blocks based on ordered datetime stamps in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, ranking

My log server collects data from client RFID readers. TagScanTimeStamp is row creation datetime in UTC

Following is the live sample data:

```
IncomingIP     ReaderID  TagID  TagScanTimeStamp

183.82.1.192        02  000007  2014-11-07 02:55:24.000
183.82.1.192        02  000007  2014-11-07 02:55:25.000
183.82.1.192        02  000007  2014-11-07 02:55:26.000
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 02:58:17.000
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 02:58:41.000
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:00:00.000
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:01:37.000
49.206.4.53         04  000003  2014-11-07 03:02:23.000
49.206.4.53         04  000003  2014-11-07 03:05:18.000
49.206.4.53         04  000003  2014-11-07 03:06:11.000
49.206.4.53         01  000002  2014-11-07 03:07:17.000
49.206.4.53         01  000002  2014-11-07 03:08:53.000
49.206.4.53         01  000002  2014-11-07 03:10:46.000
49.206.4.53         01  000002  2014-11-07 03:12:12.000
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:14:14.000
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:16:21.000
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:16:45.000
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:17:28.000
183.82.1.192        02  000004  2014-11-07 03:20:43.000
183.82.1.192        02  000004  2014-11-07 03:20:44.000
```

....
when I run the following query

```
select IncomingIP, ReaderID, TagID, TagScanTimeStamp, 
RANK() over (Partition by IncomingIP, ReaderID, TagID order by TagScanTimeStamp) as IdentityOrder 
from rt_tag_log_raw 
order by 4
```

I am getting the following results:

```
IncomingIP     ReaderID  TagID  TagScanTimeStamp        IdentityOrder

183.82.1.192        02  000007  2014-11-07 02:55:24.000     1
183.82.1.192        02  000007  2014-11-07 02:55:25.000     2
183.82.1.192        02  000007  2014-11-07 02:55:26.000     3
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 02:58:17.000     1
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 02:58:41.000     2
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:00:00.000     3
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:01:37.000     4
49.206.4.53         04  000003  2014-11-07 03:02:23.000     1
49.206.4.53         04  000003  2014-11-07 03:05:18.000     2
49.206.4.53         04  000003  2014-11-07 03:06:11.000     3
49.206.4.53         01  000002  2014-11-07 03:07:17.000     1
49.206.4.53         01  000002  2014-11-07 03:08:53.000     2
49.206.4.53         01  000002  2014-11-07 03:10:46.000     3
49.206.4.53         01  000002  2014-11-07 03:12:12.000     4
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:14:14.000     4
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:16:21.000     5
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:16:45.000     6
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:17:28.000     7
183.82.1.192        02  000004  2014-11-07 03:20:43.000     1
183.82.1.192        02  000004  2014-11-07 03:20:44.000     2
```

And I want IdentityOrder to display as follows

```
IncomingIP     ReaderID  TagID  TagScanTimeStamp        IdentityOrder

183.82.1.192        02  000007  2014-11-07 02:55:24.000     1
183.82.1.192        02  000007  2014-11-07 02:55:25.000     1
183.82.1.192        02  000007  2014-11-07 02:55:26.000     1
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 02:58:17.000     2
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 02:58:41.000     2
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:00:00.000     2
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:01:37.000     2
49.206.4.53         04  000003  2014-11-07 03:02:23.000     3
49.206.4.53         04  000003  2014-11-07 03:05:18.000     3
49.206.4.53         04  000003  2014-11-07 03:06:11.000     3
49.206.4.53         01  000002  2014-11-07 03:07:17.000     4
49.206.4.53         01  000002  2014-11-07 03:08:53.000     4
49.206.4.53         01  000002  2014-11-07 03:10:46.000     4
49.206.4.53         01  000002  2014-11-07 03:12:12.000     4
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:14:14.000     5
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:16:21.000     5
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:16:45.000     5
49.206.4.53         01  000003  2014-11-07 03:17:28.000     5
183.82.1.192        02  000004  2014-11-07 03:20:43.000     6
183.82.1.192        02  000004  2014-11-07 03:20:44.000     6
```

I want IdentityOrder to be incremented by 1 whenever there is a change in IncomingIP or ReaderID or TagID.

I have tried dense_rank() and I couldn't achieve what I want. Please let me know, if I am still not clear in explaning my requirement.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: What is the ranking based on? You mentioned timestamp, but it's still a bit unclear to me how that works.

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply and sorry for not being very clear with my requirement. I will edit and improvise my question shortly

Answer (score 0):

Isim is right, we haven't enough input for answer this question. But I think you are talking about RANK() OVER (...) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx. It allow you to group and rank your records according to custom comparisons:

```
CREATE TABLE #scans (
    Id INT,
    Name varchar(50),
    Timestamp INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO #scans VALUES
    (1, 'Soda', 1111111),
    (2, 'Coke', 1111111),
    (3, 'Beer', 1111113),
    (4, 'Wine', 1111113),
    (5, 'Water', 1111114),
    (6, 'Water', 1111115),
    (7, 'Soda', 1111111)
GO

SELECT Id, Name, Timestamp
    ,RANK() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY Timestamp ORDER BY Name DESC) AS Rank
FROM #scans
ORDER BY Rank, Name;
GO

SELECT Id, Name, Timestamp
    ,RANK() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Timestamp DESC) AS Rank
FROM #scans
ORDER BY Rank, Name;
GO

DROP TABLE #scans;
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt reply and sorry for not being very clear with my requirement. I will edit and improvise my question shortly

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
select IncomingIP, ReaderID, TagID, TagScanTimeStamp, 
Dense_Rank() over (order by IncomingIP, ReaderID, TagID) as IdentityOrder 
from #Yourtable
order by 4
```

Comment: Hi Paul, I have tried this query earlier and it is not going to work because this query will create same rank for rows (4,5,6,7) and rows(15,16,17,18). But I want different identity(ranks) for these 2 sets of rows even though the IncomingIP, readerID and TagID are same, but they are not continuous.